# using multiple tables and inserting the values into one

Tags: mysql, database, join

table 1 desc

```
'edb_actual_data_id', 'bigint(20) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', '', 'auto_increment'
'meter_parameter_type_map_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
'date_time', 'datetime', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
'input_value', 'double', 'NO', '', '', ''
'input_unit_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
'output_value', 'double', 'NO', '', '', ''
'output_unit_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
'has_been_processed', 'tinyint(1)', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
```

table 2 desc

```
'meter_parameter_type_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', '', 'auto_increment'
'name', 'varchar(50)', 'NO', 'UNI', '', ''
'unit_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
'is_negative_value', 'tinyint(1)', 'NO', '', '', ''
```

table 3 desc

```
'meter_parameter_type_map_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', '', 'auto_increment'
'meter_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
'meter_parameter_type_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
'min', 'double', 'NO', '', '', ''
'max', 'double', 'NO', '', '', ''
'meter_thread_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
'meter_parameter_name', 'varchar(100)', 'NO', '', '', ''
'baselineEnabled', 'tinyint(1)', 'NO', '', '', ''
'meter_parameter_type_map_transalation_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
```

table 4 desc

```
'meter_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', '', 'auto_increment'
'name', 'varchar(100)', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
'parent_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'YES', 'MUL', '', ''
'building_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
'meter_type_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
'add_to_parent', 'tinyint(1)', 'NO', '', '', ''
'meter_group_id', 'int(10) unsigned', 'YES', 'MUL', '', ''
```

table 5 desc

```
'Time_Stamp', 'datetime', 'YES', '', '', ''
'Meter_ID', 'int(10) unsigned', 'YES', '', '', ''
'Address', 'int(10) unsigned', 'YES', '', '', ''
'Value', 'double', 'YES', '', '', ''
```

table 6 desc

```
'ID', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', '', 'auto_increment'
'NAME', 'varchar(45)', 'NO', 'UNI', '', ''
'GROUP_ID', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
'STANDARD', 'tinyint(1)', 'NO', '', '', ''
```

these are the description of the 6 tables that i am having . I need to use the tables from table 2 to table 5 and insert into table 1 .

I am confused with the joining of these tables .

**Input_value,output_value in table 1 has to be picked from value in table 5.**

**input_unit_id ,output_unit_id in table 1 has to be picked from id in table 6 where id in table 6 = unit_id in table 2**

please can any one tell me how do i do that .

i tried the below query but i am confused what joins do i provide .

```
INSERT INTO edb_actual_data
            (meter_parameter_type_map_id,
             date_time,
             input_value,
             input_unit_id,
             output_value,
             output_unit_id,
             has_been_processed)
SELECT t2.meter_parameter_type_map_id,
       t1.time_stamp,
       t1.value,
       t3.id,
       t1.value,
       t3.id
FROM   `eb1_remote`.`eb1_test1` t1
       INNER JOIN `siruseri`.`meter_parameter_type_map` t2
       INNER JOIN `siruseri`.`meter` t4
               ON t4.meter_id = t1.meter_id
       INNER JOIN `siruseri`.`meter_parameter_type` t5
       INNER JOIN `siruseri`.`unit` t3
               ON t3.id = t5.unit_id;
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle, and show us both what you've tried and what you desire.

Comment: I have added my query , and i am very much confused with the joins that i have to use . kindly suggest .. i tried very hard , when i am not able to understand , i thought of posting it here .explaining would have been more confusing ,so i put everything

Comment: I just don't feel like wading through a sea of inverted commas.

Comment: Sorry for that .please have a look , a little pain i know

Comment: Look, I've outlined the steps that I think you should take towards solving this problem. A little pain I know.

Comment: ok ..just tell me how do i pick data with no join relation and insert into my table.thanks

Comment: If the data has no realtion, why should you put it into one table?

Answer (score 0):

If you join two tables, you have to select an identifier which both tables have.
And also you have to give the correct names to your select query:

```
INSERT INTO edb_actual_data
            (meter_parameter_type_map_id,
             date_time,
             input_value,
             input_unit_id,
             output_value,
             output_unit_id,
             has_been_processed)
SELECT t2.meter_parameter_type_map_id,
       t1.time_stamp AS date_time,
       t1.value      AS input_value,
       t3.id         AS input_unit_id,
       t1.value      AS output_value,
       t3.id         AS output_unit_id
FROM   `eb1_remote`.`eb1_test1` t1
       INNER JOIN `siruseri`.`meter_parameter_type_map` t2
               ON t1.meter_parameter_type_id = t2.meter_parameter_type_id
       INNER JOIN `siruseri`.`meter` t4
               ON t4.meter_id = t1.meter_id
       INNER JOIN `siruseri`.`meter_parameter_type` t5
               ON t5.Meter_ID = t3.meter_id
       INNER JOIN `siruseri`.`unit` t3
               ON t3.id = t5.unit_id;
```

Comment: these ?? are the problem . there is no other table column same as these.

Comment: Well table 2 has the meter_parameter_type_id, so you can join on this. (see edit)

Comment: the meter_id can be found in table 5 and table 3